# How to Export DataFrame result to an Excel File Fast in one line

Tags: python, pandas

What is the function to export data frame result to excel file in just one line?

Comment: First result on Google: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use to_excel function. here df is your result data frame.

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\bhagi\Desktop\File Name.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index = False)
```

Arguments:

```
C:\Users\bhagi\Desktop\File Name.xlsx = give your path
sheet1 = your sheet name
if you don't want the index column give index = false argument.
```

Comment: thanks can we also use a writer function in one line?